# Issue while testing a C++ program that measure levels above the sea

Tags: c++

I have a uni project the task is We flew from Europe to North America, and we measured the height above the sea level at equal sequences. The first and last measurements were either above a continent or the sea. We measured positive height, where we were above some land, and 0, where we were above the sea

I tried to make the code and now i have the code and when i enter the inputs it gives me the same output as it is supposed to be in the task.

[image]

The problem is that the code doesn't work in the university online marking system, because

1. I checked it in case there are no islands, the program prints 0 0, but it should print a single 0.
2. Also, when all the islands have 0 valleys, the program should just show output of the first island, right now the maximum selection doesn't work for this case (do you think it can fixed by changing only the initial value of maxV)

Can you please help me with these two points?

```
     #include <iostream>

int main() {
    
    // Gets the number of heights
    unsigned int height_count;
    std::cin >> height_count; 
    
    // Get every height recorded and put it in an array
    unsigned short* heights = new unsigned short[height_count];
    for (int i = 0; i < height_count; ++i)
        std::cin >> heights[i];
    
    // We need to keep track of the following things:
    int island_start = -1, max_island_start = -1, max_island_end = -1;
    unsigned current_valley_count = 0, max_valley_count = 0;
    
    
    for (int i = 1; i < height_count-1; ++i) {
        if (heights[i] > 0 && heights[i-1] == 0) // If the coast starts
            island_start = i;
        else if (heights[i] > 0 && heights[i] <= heights[i-1] && heights[i] <= heights[i+1] && !(heights[i] == heights[i-1]) + (heights[i] == heights[i+1]) == 1) // If there is a valley
            ++current_valley_count;
        else if (heights[i] > 0 && heights[i+1] == 0) { // If the coast ends
            
            // Checks if the last island checked had the most valleys
            if (current_valley_count > max_valley_count) {
                max_island_start = island_start;
                max_island_end = i;
                max_valley_count = current_valley_count;
            }
            
            island_start = -1;
            current_valley_count = 0;
        }
    }
    
    
    std::cout << max_island_start+1 << " " << max_island_end+1 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I cannot understand the problem: Why the output for the example input is not `8 10` but `3 6`? According to the definition, the island `1 3 1 4` seems having 0 valleys because no consecutive measurements has same values but the isnald `2 1 1` has 1 valley.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print single `0` instead of `0 0`, you should add `if` statement to check if there were no islands and change what to print according to that.

Also, the initial value of `max_valley_count` should be `-1` instead of `0` so that the (first) island with 0 valleys can appear in the output.
I don't think the issue can be fixed by changing initial value of `maxV` because `maxV` is not used in this code.

As one more point, the problem statement says

> but only one of B=A and B=C is true

On the other hand, your program says

```
!(heights[i] == heights[i-1]) + (heights[i] == heights[i+1]) == 1
```

This part of code means "only one of B**!=**A and B=C is true".

You should delete the `!`.

Comment: Ok Thanks
ALso,I checked it in case there is a single island and then the code has to print that. for example: 
3 
0 2 0 the result should be 2 2